# Will unused spare razor blades rust if stored for a long time?

Tags: metal

I am considering purchasing 16 razor blade spares for a reduced price, but am unsure if they will be good as new if I were to use them several months from now.

If left alone in the packaging (they come in plastic cartridge cases with one side exposed), will the quality degrade by the time I use the last several (if the blades were replaced monthly)?

Comment: If you store it properly, and if the blades are of good quality... there will be no appreciable rusting by the time you use them ;) [ "Store properly" = Minimize contact with moisture-laden air]

Comment: @paracetamol. Would keeping them in a drawer in the cabinet attached to the bathroom sink suffice? Would that be enough to store properly?

Answer (score 2):

Aside from storing a in **dry** location, you might use a [vapor corrosion inhibitor (VCI)](http://www.armorvci.com/) in a container with the blades. [Amazon offers a similar product for ~US$11.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00ULSW6FS)

My experience has been that VCI is effective and does not leave a noticeable film that needs to be removed. Whether this is cost-effective for your intended use is another question (perhaps you can use the remaining VCI on other objects or share with ten other people).

And then, beards are even more cost-effective ;-)